# Questions about AIX passwd file

Tags: aix, passwd

I'm a beginner in AIX and I have 2 questions on AIX's passwd file.

1. If there is a hash (#) symbol in front of a username, what does
   this mean?
2. Correct me if I'm wrong. On the password field, if a
   user has password, it will be marked with an asterisk symbol (*). If
   a user does not have a password, it is marked with an exclamation
   mark (!) and that the account is locked / blocked.

Thanks

Comment: have you read the manpage? Or [IBM's most excellent documentation (check out the "files reference" section, or search)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp)? The answer to at least one of your questions is in the documentation - The other may be as well...

Answer (score 0):

1. The hash in front of a username means that the user effectively does not exist. This is a TERRIBLE way to remove a user though. If you want to remove user, make sure you use rmuser. If you want to lock an account do chuser  account_locked=true.
2. This is incorrect.

To see if a user has a password or not, check /etc/security/passwd. If there is no password hash underneath the users name, then they do not have a password set. To check to see if a user is locked, do `lsuser <user>` and look for account_locked.